# ggplot geom_bar leave blank spaces for 0 values by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is a simple ggplot bar plot:

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
    y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,2,1,1,1,1,1)
    d<-cbind(x,y)
    
    ggplot(data=d,aes(x=x,fill=as.factor(y)))+
      geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

The issue I'm having is that each value of y is not present in each grouping x. So for example, group 1 along the x-axis only contains groups 1-5 of the y variable, and doesn't have any values for 6 or 7. What I would like is for the plot to leave blank spaces when there is are no values for a y in the given x-grouping, this way it is easier to compare the x-groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to compute the frequencies manually and plot the graph based on that frequencies table.

```
library(ggplot2)

d1 <- data.frame(table(d))
d1$x <- factor(d1$x)

ggplot(d1, aes(x, Freq, fill = factor(y))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error when I run your code. The table I get as output has not column "x", only a column d and a column Freq. Are you on a V3 or V4 instance of R? I know there were some changes in Cbind with the new version.

Comment: Got it. V4 of R requires data.frame(cbind(x,y))

Comment: @TannerPhillips No, don't use the construct `data.frame(cbind(.))`. In this case it makes no difference butif one of the vectors is not numeric both will be coerced to character because `cbind` creates a matrix and matrices can only have one type of data

Answer (score 0):

[image: updated figure]

```
library(tidyverse)

# set factor levels
d2 <- d %>% data.frame() %>% mutate(x=factor(x, levels=c(1:3)), 
             y=factor(y, levels=c(1:7))) 

# count frequencies and send to ggplot2
d2 %>% group_by(x, y, .drop=F) %>% tally() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=n, fill=y, color=y)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(), 
           stat="identity")
```

Another way to do this using dplyr is to use `tally()` to count the frequencies, but you need to make sure that you have your variables set as factors first.

Using `color=y` & `fill=y` in the `aes` statement helps to show exactly where on the plot the zero values are. So, now you can see that it is y=6 & y=7 missing from x=1 & x=3, and y=1 missing from x=2

And I chose `position_dodge2` for my own personal preferences.